# Will component re-render even if we do not pass props to it?

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and wanted to ask if, be it a functional or class component, re-render even if we do not pass props to it at all. For simplicity sake, let's imagine `<Counter><Input/></Counter>`. So we have counter component and inside of which we have input component. The question is when we change state in counter component will input component rerender EVEN IF we do not pass any props to input?

}

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Input is a child or Counter component and is passed on as `children` prop to Counter.

Input component will not re-render if the state within the Counter is updated and counter re-renders.

However If the component that renders `Counter` and `Input` component re-renders, both of these components will get rerendered unless you implement them as a `PureComponent`

Attaching a small demo for proof of concept.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
     toggle: false
  }
  render() {
     return (
        <div>
          <Counter><Input /></Counter>
          <div><button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState(prev=> ({toggle: !prev.toggle}))}>Toggle App state</button></div>
         </div>
     )
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
   state = {
      count: 0
   }
   
   componentDidMount() {
     this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prev => ({count: prev.count + 1}));
     }, 1000)
   }
   
   render() {
    console.log('counter render');
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>Counter: {this.state.count}</div>
        {this.props.children}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
   }
}

const Input = () => {
   console.log('Input render');
   return (
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" />
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: hi Shubham, so you mean if state inside Counter gets changed then Input component which is a child of Counter will NOT rerender Right?